# Gitで管理しているバッチファイルを mac で実行権限ありで保存するには？

Tags: git, macos, command-line

IPアドレスを取得するバッチファイル(*.command)を作成する事ができたのですが、
作成しただけですと実行権限がないのでダブルクリックで実行する事ができず
ターミナルから chmod を使って権限付与する必要があります。

デザイナーさんに使用してもらう為のバッチファイルなので実行権限付与をターミナルから打たせたくないのですが、バッチファイル保存時に実行権限も付与する方法はないでしょうか？

■バッチファイルの中身

```
LANG=C /sbin/ifconfig | grep 'inet ' | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2;}' | cut -d: -f2
```

■環境
　MaxOSX：10.10.3

■ファイルの受け渡し
ファイルはGitで管理しておりSourceTree経由でファイルを渡す事になります。

Comment: 通常権限はファイルに保持されると思いますがデザイナーさんが権限を設定しないとけない何か事情がお有りですか？デザイナーさんへのファイルの受け渡しはどのように行うのでしょうか。

Comment: SourceTree経由でファイルを渡す事になります。　そしてバッチファイルをダブルクリックしてもらう予定でして今は自分のMacでバッチファイルのテストしている状況です。

Comment: gitコマンドは実行できますか？ `git update-index --chmod=+x filename` でファイルに明示的に実行権限を指定できるそうです。

Comment: 実行権限付与後にコミットしたファイルを実行するとダブルクリックして実行できました。

Comment: うまく言ったようですね。改めて回答にまとめておきます。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

元々実行権限を設定したファイルを Git リポジトリに入れた時点でファイルのアクセス許可が変わってしまったのが原因だと思います。

ファイルの実行権限を明示的に指定するには `git update-index` コマンドで `--chmod=+x` オプションを指定します。

```
$ git update-index--chmod=+x filename
```

逆に実行権限を外す場合は `--chmod=-x` を指定します。

```
$ git update-index--chmod=-x filename
```

Comment: スタックオーバーフローがお礼を言ってはいけない風習なのは知っているのですが、簡潔に素晴らしい回答いただけたので大変感謝しております。
ありがとうございました。